# Find probability that at least one box contains a total of $6$ or more balls when $10$ balls are selected

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a total of 50 balls numbered 1 to 50.
I have 4 boxes:

- Box 1 range 1 to 15
- Box 2 range 16 to 30
- Box 3 range 31 to 45
- Box 4 range 46 to 50

I pick 10 balls at random from those numbered 1 to 50 each round. 
I place each ball in one of the 4 boxes according to range.

**e.g**

**If I pick the number 13 ball, place it in Box 1**
**If I pick the number 30 ball, place it in Box 2**

What is the probability that **Box 1** or **Box 2** or **Box 3** contain a total of 6 or more balls?

Please explain briefly with the equation.

**Thanks.**

Comment: Is the picking done with or without replacement?

Comment: Are you asking how many selections result in at least $6$ numbers being placed in one box?

Comment: The principle of [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) should be a useful tool here.  We have the convenience also of it being impossible for multiple boxes to each get 6 or more balls simultaneously so a great deal of the effort in using inclusion-exclusion is reduced.  Now... ask yourself, what is the probability that box 1 contains $6$ or more balls?  To answer that, what is the probability that box 1 contains exactly $6$ balls?  exactly $7$ balls? etc...

Answer (score 2):

The context shows, that the picking is without repetition, so:

1. Notice, that if we pick 10 balls, there can be at last one box with 6 or more bals in it. Events where there are 6 or more balls in box n are disjoint, so
   $$P=P(6 \text{ or more in Box1 or Box2 or Box3}) = \\ P(6 \text{ or more in Box1})+P(6 \text{ or more in Box2})+P(6 \text{ or more in Box3})$$
2. Events for box1, box2 and box3 are the same - 15 balls are in the range, 35 bals are outside the range. So 
   $$P(6 \text{ or more in Box1})=P(6 \text{ or more in Box2})=P(6 \text{ or more in Box3}) = Q$$
3. The space of all pickings have $$|\Omega|=\binom{50}{10}$$ elements
4. For $k\geq 6$ event where there are exactly $k$ balls in box n can be described as: Pick $k$ balls of 15 that fits in box n and $10-k$ balls of 35 that fits in the other boxes. It can be done in
   $$a_k=\binom{15}{k}\binom{35}{10-k}$$
   ways.
5. Obviously the events, where there are exactly 6,7,8,9 and 10 elements in box n are disjoint, so
   $$Q=\frac{\sum_{k=6}^{10}a_k}{|\Omega|}$$
6. Finally
   $$P=3Q = \frac{3\sum_{k=6}^{10}\binom{15}{k}\binom{35}{10-k}}{\binom{50}{10}}$$

Comment: Probability for that answer was 0.02551155602, i am right @Jaroslaw Matlak